# No layer available in the response of GetCapabilites request

Tags: geoserver, getcapabilities

I am doing a GetCapabilites request on geoserver to get the bounding box of wms layer but in the response, i am only getting a bunch of EPSG projections but no layers?
this is the request i am using:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0
```

Also i have read the documentation of get capabilities https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#wms-getcap
and they have mentioned a **namespace** parameter to bound the result of GetCapabilites request to a specific layer,what should be the value of this parameter ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using version=1.0.0 instead of 1.1.1 or 1.3.0?  Do you have anything like an isolated workspace in use?

Comment: nope, I tried changing the value of version still no response

Comment: i you have put everything in an isolated workspace you may need something like http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WORKSPACENAME/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0

Comment: to answer your question it may be something like WorkspaceName:LayerName

Comment: This is a typical response from WMS Service https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities. WMS 1.3.0 shows bounding boxes a bit better than earlier versions but 1.1.1 should work for you as well. GeoServers do not support WMS 1.0.0 but if you ask for it you are actually getting WMS 1.1.1 response back. You wrote you do not get layers in GetCapabilities; are you sure? Look at the end of the document.

Comment: what does the log file show?

Comment: @IanTurton the log file shows this :- Request: getCapabilities BaseUrl = localhost:8081/geoserver Get = false Namespace = //name RawKvp = {NAMESPACE=//name, REQUEST=GetCapabilities, VERSION=1.3.0, SERVICE=WMS} Request = GetCapabilities RequestCharset = null UpdateSequence = null Version = 1.3.0

Comment: try turning the logging level up to debug and try again

Comment: @IanTurton  actually there is only one workspace available on my geoserver(created by me)and i have deleted the default ones so now when i request:  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/<my_workspace>/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0 and this is also showing no layers?

Comment: @IanTurton also I turn the logging level to debug and now its says :  Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[geo_analytics], available services were [WCSInfoImpl[WCS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS]]